# Evaluating $\int x^n e^{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I consider, for $n=0,1,2,...$,  $$ u_n(x)=\int x^n e^{x}dx.$$ I've performed an integration by parts giving $$ u_n(x)=nx^{n-1} e^{x}-nu_{n-1}(x).$$ I'm looking for a closed form. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.integraltec.com/math/math.php?f=xnExpx.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start integrating by parts and and draw a patern from there.

$$\int x^n e^x dx= x^n e^x -n\int x^{n-1} e^x dx = x^n e^x -n\left (x^{n-1}e^x -(n-1) \int x^{n-2} e^x dx \right )=\cdots$$

We can conclude that $$\int x^n e^x dx = e^x \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}x^{n-i}$$

But $$\Gamma(n,x)=(n-1)!e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

I believe you can draw conclusions.